# Reset Timer every x minutes/hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying two create to separate timers. One timer counts down to a date and displays a countdown and the other counts down on an interval and resets (ie: 5 hours and resets).

The one I am having trouble with is the second option. I am trying to create a countdown that is relative to real-time and then resets once it reaches zero. So for example setting it to 2 days and 5 hours. Once this completes the clock resets to 2 days 5 hours. I am having trouble getting the clock to reset at the specified time and loop without having negative numbers. I tried this two separate ways but feel like I am over-complicating things.

The reason I use real-time is so that the clock will be the same if you open it in another tab. If I create a regular timer it will reset upon refreshing the page.

[codpen](https://codepen.io/teomhk/pen/ejmxLp)

In this example I tried to reset the counter every 40 seconds but couldn't get it to work. Ultimately I want to be able to specify the date with ie: 00:12:00 (12 hours countdown) and then have it reset automatically. I just can't figure out how to maintain the counting without going to negative numbers or freezing it.

```
function timer() {
    var currentTime = new Date()

    var date = currentTime.getDate()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    var daysLeft = 0;
    var hoursLeft = 24 - hours;
    var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
    var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;


    // counter freezes at 40 seconds and hangs for 20seconds
    if(secsLeft => 40) {
       secsLeft = 40 - seconds
       if(secsLeft < 0) {
         secsLeft = 40 
       }
    }

document.getElementById('timerUpFront').innerHTML= "<br><br><strong>Duration Countdown with Infinite Reset #2</strong><br>" + daysLeft + " days " + hoursLeft + " hours " + minsLeft + " minutes " + secsLeft + " seconds";
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

[codpen](https://codepen.io/teomhk/pen/ejmxLp)

Comment: Have you tried checking `if (daysLeft <= 0 && hoursLeft <= 0 && minsLeft <= 0 && secsLeft <= 0 ) { 
// reset action 
}`, if I didn't misunderstand that's what you need (when it's 00:00:00:00 it resets).

Comment: correct, I'd like it to restart counting down. I am unclear of how to reset the action though.

Comment: Ok, I will try to write a whole code in an answer 
And explain some concepts about controling timers.

Answer (score 2):

you can separate the timer to functions to simplify it and apply the following logic

```
function startTimer () {
  val targetRemainedSeconds = // calculate the value
  val remainedSeconds = targetRemainedSeconds
  setInterval(timer(), 1000)
}
function timer () {
  remainedSeconds--
  if (remainedSeconds < 0) reaminedSeconds = targetReaminedSeconds // reset the timer 
  timerUpdate()
}
function timerUpdate() {
  // use 'remainedSeconds' to update timer 
}
```